# Wiring issue with a light fixture and ceiling wiring

Tags: wiring, ceiling, circuit

On my ceiling there is a black, red, ground, white wire. However we got a chandelier and it has a ground, red, and a black wire. The light fixture also has a white wire but the owner said it is for the remote control and I don't believe we use it because it is not stripped. Where would each wire go?

Comment: pictures will help, and could you please clarify what, "...there are two but one seems to be pulled from somewhere..."  means.

Comment: Pictures are needed.  A simple light fixture should only need a black and white, and maybe ground(ceiling and light).  The extra red should not be needed usually.  What wires are at the switch?  Is this just a light or a ceiling fan with a light(red would useful then)?

Comment: How about brand/model of the (presumably) new light. Maybe even a link to the instructions (you did read those, right)? Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: I clarified it a little more however I can't add a picture because it says it is too large, hope the explanation is better.